# match 9 digits in string where there are more than 9 digits

Tags: regex, oracle

I have an oracle table with a column that is varchar2(4000).  I want to be able to find 9 consecutive digits and replace it with xxxxxxxxx. if there are more than 9 consecutive digits, I don't want to replace those digits. I've tried

```
regexp_replace('this is my string of digits 987654321889890','\d{9}','xxxxxxxxx')
```

but this would return `'this is my string of digits xxxxxxxxx889890'`

In this case I would want the regexp engine to ignore any substring of more than 9 consecutive digits.

Thanks in advance
Joey

Comment: What would is intended to  happen if there are 2 or more sets of 9 consecutive digits?

Comment: And this very well could happen. I would want regex_replace to replace all occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

This should produce the expected result:

```
regexp_replace(str, '(^|[^0-9])([0-9]{9})($|[^0-9])', '\1xxxxxxxxx\3')
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/38554 for a live example

Answer (score 0):

Sylvain already posted a similar answer.

With the 11.1 Oracle database, one can utilize character groupings into the replace pattern.
See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm#SQLRF06302).

Like Sylvain, the key was creating a match pattern encapsulated by character sets which one could replace the nine repeating digits with the 'xxxxxxxxx'.

**Steps to the solution:**

1. Create three character sets for the matching pattern.
2. Use the alternation operator to account for the possibility of having beginning and/or end of lines instead of non-numeric characters.
3. Create the replacement pattern: character set 1 | 'xxxxxxxxx' | character set 3.

Here is my example solution:

```
    SCOTT@dev> list
  1  WITH t AS
  2    (SELECT 'this is my string of digits 987654321889890' txt_val FROM dual
  3    UNION
  4    SELECT 'this is my string of digits 54321889890' FROM dual
  5    UNION
  6    SELECT 'this is my string of digits 987654321' FROM dual
  7    UNION
  8    SELECT 'this is my string of digits 98761189890' FROM dual
  9    UNION
 10    SELECT 'this is my string of digits 121889890' FROM dual
 11    )
 12  SELECT t.txt_val,
 13    regexp_replace(t.txt_val,'([^0-9]|^)(\d{9})([^0-9]|$)','\1xxxxxxxxx\3') txt_val_fixed
 14* FROM t
SCOTT@dev> /

TXT_VAL                                     TXT_VAL_FIXED
=========================================== ================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
this is my string of digits 121889890       this is my string of digits xxxxxxxxx
this is my string of digits 54321889890     this is my string of digits 54321889890
this is my string of digits 98761189890     this is my string of digits 98761189890
this is my string of digits 987654321       this is my string of digits xxxxxxxxx
this is my string of digits 987654321889890 this is my string of digits 987654321889890
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the helpful information. I wound up using

JAM@DEV>select regexp_replace('987654653this is my number 950569808890 now its not 878788976 and this one is less than 8823727 one more 950877665',
  '(\D|^)(\d{9})(\D|$)', ' xxx-xx-xxxx ',1,0,'m') "regexpreplace" from dual;

### regexpreplace

xxx-xx-xxxx his is my number 950569808890 now its not xxx-xx-xxxx and this one
is less than 8823727 one more xxx-xx-xxxx